# The reason why will the VDC influence the output of comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, delay

There is my schematic,teacher gave us,for the comparator, Theoretically,when the black line is bigger than blue,the red one will become "signal one".but i found the vdc value will influence the output wave,why ?which VDC value is the suitable for this comparator?how do i know that?

[image]

You can see the pictures below for different VDC

1. VDC=1.8V,and the output(red) are all "signal one"
   [image]

2.VDC=5V,and actually we can know the comparator does work,but i am not sure that the comparator work correctly or wrong,or just have big delay.
[image]

3.There are VDC=10V and 15V,and we can compare them with the wave for VDC=5V,we can found the "signal one become thinner",and i think the delay become shorter
[image]
[image]

4.VDC=50V,and the wave does't become shorter,it becomes fatter,and there is a pulse when the signal change(0 to 1 or 1 to 0),and the delay time is shorter and shorter
[image]

Comment: Could you tell us a bit about your setup? Is this a pure simulation and if so, what's the software? Or have you built it up on a PCB, and in that case, how did you build it? Most important: What's the comparator?

Comment: I'm not sure I know of any comparators that would be expected to work over the range 1.8v to 50v!

Comment: @pipe i don't understand "a bit about your setup " you said,the software is " cadence virtuoso",i have not built it up a PCB.comparator is something that a compare two input,if one of inputs is bigger than another one,than the output will be 1 or 0

Comment: If you are indeed driving the part at a frequency of around 40 MHz, then you need to consider electrical characteristics such as slew rate (or response time, or bandwidth), output impedance, etc., all of which will affect the part's ability (or inability) to switch the output voltage at the dV/dt rates you're attempting. And of course, applying a u(t) step voltage at the inputs does not instantaneously result in a u(t) step voltage at the output; there will always be some propagation delay from input to output.

Comment: @Neil_UK i think no,i just want to know the influence of VDC to comparator output

Comment: @JimFischer but as you can see,the VDC value not only influence the output wave shape but also the delay time.Why?how do i now which value for VDC is better?

Comment: there is no such thing as 'a comparator' There are lots of different comparators, and lots of different models for them. They behave slightly differently to each other, and their behaviour will change as input frequency, rail voltage, input voltages, rise times, everything really, temperature as well, change. What model is your simulator using?

Comment: The answer depends heavily on the specific part you are using, or in this case, with the SPICE model you are using. If the input signal's switching speed, or the comparator's output voltage slew rate is too extreme, the transistors in the comparator can not follow the input signal and you'll end up with a distorted output signal. The distortion seen with low VCC voltages could have multiple causes--e.g., the low VCC voltage is preventing the comparator's internal circuitry from operating in its linear region.

Comment: @Neil_UK very sorry,I will add the schematic later

Comment: @Neil_UK i have add it.

Comment: So you're trying to _design_ a comparator. This is extremely important information and changes the answers drastically.